# Xcode: Saving core data with 1-Many relationships?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, cocos2d-iphone

Suppose I have a 'Tree' entity and an 'Apple' entity in my core data.

A tree has attributes like age and height, and to save these I just pull the tree from the context, edit the variables and save it back.

But if a tree has many apples how do I go about this? I set up a one-to-many relationship but I'm not sure how to 'add' apples to my tree object in the context. Like do I insert a new entity for each apple?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new NSManagedObject for each Apple. Then you can add an apple to the tree using the [Core Data Generated Accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html).

```
[tree addApplesObject:apple];
```

Comment: Thanks! How should these NSManagedObjects be created though, can I just alloc and init then add it?